# C# kubernetes-client Domain-Driven Design

Tags: .net, kubernetes, domain-driven-design

I am new to DDD design and currently developing a feature that requires kubernetes-client.
I have Kubernete service and mapping service in the infrastructure layer. should I add the kubernete service and mapping service interface in Domain layer? if the answer is yes, how can I handle the kubernetes-client return type in the interface? I added the kubernetes-client nuget in the infrastructure layer. if the answer is No, where should I keep the service interface?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to decide whether Kubernetes is part of your domain or not (probably not) and then, model it into Entities and Domain Services or Infrastructure Services.

There is no right anwser for this, it depends a lot on your use case and your application,  but I'd probably go for creating an interface that abstract out what Kubernetes has to do (to not have infrastructures leaks into your domain layer) "OrchestrationService" or something like that, create an implementation of it "KubernetesOrchestrationServices" and then inject it via DI. Thus, you can create other implementations (like mocks at testing time) for this service and not depend on external libraries or implementations.

Hope this helps.